# DBUnit: can meta table data be stored along XML file

Tags: java, dbunit

I'd like to know if there is a way to store and retrieve meta table data along with the full or flat XML files, primarily information about the primary keys of the database schema.

Answer (score 0):

dbUnit reads the DB metadata while processing but doesn't store it.  All of its operations are for data processing.  It has a "write DTD" option, which might do what you are looking for: http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#generatedtd.  Otherwise, you could add a feature option to save other metadata, if inclined.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Unfortunately the DTD file does not save the primary keys. I tested it with the DefaultTable and DefaultDataSet and a MS SQL database.

Comment: Is it worth adding an option to flag the PKs in the output?

Comment: For my particular case yes. I am implementing a black box test and we have multiple tables which will be updated periodically. And the update will erase each entry and insert them again. Together with added or updated rows. Deleted rows just don&#39;t appear again. And the order of the insertion is not guaranteed. Therefore I need the primary keys to identify rows which have been added or deleted.
I have a workaround for this use case so it's not a big deal. I was just wondering if there is a native solution in DBUnit.